# How can I specify which instances of a class are unmarshalled using an XMLAdapter?

Tags: jaxb

I have the following java class and have placed an XmlJavaAdapter annotation on the payerPartyReference variable. I want the adapter PartyReferenceAdapter to be used for unmarshalling ONLY this variable, not any other variables which have the same type of PartyReference, whether in this class or some other class. How can I do this? Thanks for your help!

```
public class InitialPayment extends PaymentBase
{

    // Want PartyReferenceAdapter to be used here
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PartyReferenceAdapter.class)
    protected PartyReference payerPartyReference;
    //
    // Dont want PartyReferenceAdapter to be used here
    protected PartyReference receiverPartyReference;
    //
    protected AccountReference receiverAccountReference;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar adjustablePaymentDate;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar adjustedPaymentDate;
    protected Money paymentAmount;
}
```

My Adapter is defined as follows:

```
public class PartyReferenceAdapter 
    extends XmlAdapter < Object, PartyReference > {

  public PartyReference unmarshal(Object obj) throws Exception {

     Element element = null;

     if (obj instanceof Element) {

        element = (Element)obj;

        String reference_id = element.getAttribute("href");
        PartyReference pr = new PartyReference();
        pr.setHref(reference_id);                   
        return pr;

    }

    public Object marshal(PartyReference arg0) throws Exception {
     return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Field/Property Level**

If you set `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on a field/property it will only be used for that property.

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

**Type Level**

If you set `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on a type, then it will used for all references to that type.

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

**Package Level**

If you set `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on a package, then it will be used for all references to that type within that package:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Comment: The first case is definitely what I want, but its not working that way even though I set the Adapter only on the property "PartyReference payerPartyReference;" as shown above.. Any ideas? Could it be because I have this same property,  "PartyReference payerPartyReference" in many other classes and the adapter is also getting applied to those because they have the same name and type?  I edited my original question to include the adapter.

Comment: And thank you for your explanation of the three levels! .. Now if I can just getting working on the first level.. its acting more like the package level..

Comment: I figured out why the setting the adapter on the field/property level didn't seem to work.. There was another class that was extending the class having the adapter.. Therefore whenever either class was used, the adapter was getting called. Thanks again for your help